# Replacing every 4th line of a file with the corresponding line in another file

Tags: replace, sed

I have a situation where I would like to replace every 4th line of a large file with the corresponding line from another file, starting at line 1 (so line 1, 5, 9, etc.).

I have tried using sed but cannot figure out how to use every 4th line of the second file as input for the substitution.

So far I have:

```
sed '1~4 s/.*/?/' original-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

What can I use instead of the "?" to correctly replace the lines?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I see something that involves more than a simple thinking, I remove `sed` from my brain and try doing it with `awk`. Probably I am too `awk`-biased, but I do think that the way it stores data and has access to the line numbers is way better and easier to understand that `sed`'s.

So, let's use [the `FNR==NR` trick](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) to check one file and then the other:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {data[FNR]=$0; next}  # store data from file 1
     (FNR%4==1){                   # in file 2, if line number is (4k + 1)
         $0=data[FNR]              # replace with the same line from the 1st file
     }1' file1 file2               # print the line
```

The key here is to store all the data from the file 1 in the array `data[]`, with the index of every line being its line number.

Then, when reading the file 2, a line is replaced with the corresponding line of file 1 if its number is a multiple of 4.

See an example with a sequence from 100 to 110 having numbers from 1 to 10 interleaved:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {data[FNR]=$0; next} (FNR%4==1){$0=data[FNR]}1' <(seq 10) <(seq 100 110)
1
101
102
103
5
105
106
107
9
109
110
```

Comment: fyi: OP's wordings don't reflect the `sed` command though which works on lines 1,5,9,13, etc

Comment: Ah yes, I will edit this into my question. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @spasic thanks for the observation. `FNR%4==1` should make. Let's see what the OP updates with.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me in my case. Although I did find out my awk skills are still lacking.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using perl, here's a small script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open my $fh1,'<','original-file.txt' or die;
open my $fh2,'<','other-file.txt' or die;
open my $out,'>','output-file.txt' or die;
my $n=0;
while (<$fh1>) {
    my $s=<$fh2>;
    print $out ($n++ % 4 == 0 ? $s : $_);
}
```

This will avoid loading the data in memory and thus operate in constant memory.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1~4!d' file2 | sed $'1~4{R/dev/stdin\n;d}' file1 > outFile
```

This uses 2 invocations of sed and pipes the result of the first into the second using the filename `/dev/stdin`. Also using bashes `$'...'` to insert a linefeed into the second invocation.